# How do I send the generated pdf file as multiform data in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf

I have generated a pdf file from html and I want to send it to my back end to save it.

```js
saveFile(): void{
    var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');  
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
      // Few necessary setting options  
      var imgWidth = 208;   
      var pageHeight = 315;    
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;  

      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
      let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
      console.log(contentDataURL);
      var position = 0;  
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight); 
      // Generated PDF   
      pdf.save('certificate.pdf');
      let blob = new Blob([contentDataURL], {type: "image/png"})
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", blob);
      this.certificateService.saveFile(formData).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(blob);
      }, err=>{
        console.log(err);
      });
    });    
  }
```

This is the function I use to send the supposed form data but the back end gives the following error.

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

How can I send the generated pdf file to back end?